# How to inject configuration from subproject only if it is part of compilation

Tags: c++, gradle

I created a plugin `XYZ` that must inject configuration in all projects (from the root).

My project is a [native C++ project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/native_software.html) for Visual Studio. Hence Java dependencies are not available...

Here is my layout, both variant uses the common lib `projLib`. `projVariant1` uses the plugin but `projVariant2` does not.

```
myRoot
 - projLib
 - projVariant1 <- uses the plugin
 - projVariant2
```

Build `projVariant1` should produce: `myRoot#XYZ`, `projLib#XYZ`, `projVariant1#XYZ`

Build `projVariant2` should produce: `myRoot`, `projLib`, `projVariant2`

My idea is to do something like this (pseudo code) :

```
def applyPluginXYZ(Project p) {
    p.if_part_of_compilation { // <-- this does not exist
        p.rootProject.subprojects {
            // apply change
        }
    }
}
```

`projVariant1`'s build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'
applyPluginXYZ(project)
```

Comment: I don't really see the relation to the C++ tag you added? Are you managing a C++ project using Gradle? Is the problem related to C++ in any other way? If not then that's probably information that's not really needed.

Comment: It is for a native project I forgot to specify (I will add some infos)